# Importing contacts from hotmail on ipad gives server error after authentication

Tags: ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, contacts, hotmail

On one of our MVC4 .NET websites we're implementing a contact importer, using the webservice from `<a href="http://stescodes.com/grabcontacts.aspx">stesCodes</a>`. Everything works fine, until we tried to import contacts from hotmail using an iPad. After choosing for an import from hotmail we're redirected to an authentication page on hotmail. After logging in with an hotmail account, we're supposed to be redirected to a page to specify the duration of this authentication. But on an iPad we're presented with a

> Server Error in '/pp1350' Application

This is an error given by *consent.live.com/error.aspx* so it's not generated on our website, but somewhere in the authentication at the hotmail server.

Our Windows Live API seems to be configured correctly, since we are able to import contacts from hotmail on other devices/browsers. Even while using Safari on a PC everything works fine.

Is anyone one of you familiar with this error?

Comment: This has been resolved in http://socialinviter.com

Answer (score 0):

Windows live have updated their API to oAuth 2.0, upgrade it to 2.0, then this error will be solved.